# How to get handle on addr of client which lost connection?

Tags: udp, python-asyncio

I have a UDP server implemented using the template in the documentation, which can be found here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-protocol.html#udp-echo-server-protocol

I would like to know the addr of the client which lost connection. The *connection_lost* callback only has a single parameter, *exc* for the exception.

Edit: Following the downvotes I want to highlight that its not a very noob-friendly part of the module naming a callback in the datagram ServerProtocol class '`connection_made`'.

Comment: There is no such thing as a connection in UDP, so there can really be no connection-lost event either.

Comment: Forgive me but why is there a callback called 'connection_made' then?

Comment: I agree with the comment in your edit. It's not. It is also very poorly documented.

Answer (score 0):

The Python API designers need to document this properly.

It looks like `connection_made()` is called when you create the socket *and connect it*, [which in turn only happens if you specify a non-`None` `Remote_addr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.AbstractEventLoop.create_datagram_endpoint).

To understand all that, first you need to understand what `connect()` does to a UDP socket at the Berkeley Sockets API level:

1. It conditions the socket so that `write() and`send()`can be used as well as`sendto()`, both of which will only send to the connected target address.
2. It conditions the socket to filter out all datagrams that did not originate at the connect target.
3. It does *not* create a wire connection of any kind. Nothing is received by the peer or sent on the wire in any way.
4. You can `connect()` a UDP socket multiple times, either to a different address or to null, which completely undoes (1) and (2).

So, I can only imagine that the `connection_lost()` callback is called when (4) happens, which it isn't in your code.

Whatever it does, if anything, it certainly can't be used to detect when a client disconnects, as there is no such event in UDP.

Comment: Note: I am not a Python guy and have not tested any of this. I am here reasoning from first principles.

Comment: `connection_made` [is invoked](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ab4a1988fd4347484a7928394b94e2cdf5f8f2a7/Lib/asyncio/selector_events.py#L949) regardless of whether `connect()` is invoked at the C socket API level. (If `remote_addr` is not provided, `address` in that constructor will be None.) This is likely because `connection_made` is the way an asyncio "protocol" is connected to the "transport". `connection_lost` is apparently called when the transport [is closed](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ab4a1988fd4347484a7928394b94e2cdf5f8f2a7/Lib/asyncio/selector_events.py#L1037).